# Is there a keyword or operator for "nor"?

Tags: programming-languages, operators, boolean, logical-operator

Is there an operator equivalent of [nor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nor)? For example, my favorite color is neither green nor blue.

And the code would be equivalent to:

```
// example one
if (color!="green" && color!="blue") { 

}

// example two
if (x nor y) {
    // x is false and y is false
}
```

Comment: No, because we already have `or` and `!`, and because double negatives are rarely used - most people find them especially hard to read.

Comment: @KilianFoth is right. Nevertheless downvotes should be for bad questions, not for questions we don't like. Furthermore, there are already three votes to close the question because it would be "opinion based", despite the question being totally neutral and non controversial (either there are such operators in some exotic language or there are't).

Comment: Is there a name for it? Yes: nor. Is it an operator? In what language? And given a language, you could look that up in the spec/docs.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: I think the downvotes is because of the title can be read as "is there a name for the definition of *nor*?" which is a silly question. But asking whether any language have a nor-operator is a legitimate question.

Comment: What is wrong about negating all the if condition ? `if(!(color!="green" && color!="blue"))`

Comment: @KilianFoth "Double negative" does not refer to a logical nor. It's a language term; it refers to applying an extra negative (some form of "not") to a verb when the object of the verb is already negative, e.g. "I didn't say nothing."

Comment: @Troyer Your comment demonstrates the problem: you got the logic wrong. ;) That isn't equivalent to a nor.

Comment: In languages with more operators, this would be (for example, in python) `color not in ['green', 'blue']`

Comment: The second one (also in python) could be `not any([x, y])`

Comment: (Basically, the two are conceptually different:  A series of comparisons vs a set of true/false)

Comment: If someone actually makes something like this, I think they should make a broader operator (I'll represent it as `$`) that allows for such as this: `x!=5$4$8`, which means you could also use other operators besides `!=` to be repeated.

Comment: Of course, you could make a precompile script to exchange your own symbol with the desired repetition, which would be `x!=5 and x!=4 and x!=8` in my example above.

Comment: 4 "primarily opinion based" close votes for a question that is *definitely* not opinion based? WTF? That is one of those cases were I really wish there were a ["keep open" close vote option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298520/directly-vote-to-not-close-a-question).

Comment: Nor is clearly a bad name, it should be Neither.

Comment: In languages where custom operators can be defined, like Haskell, Scala, or Standard ML/Ocaml, this is certainly possible.

Answer (score 73):

Although mainstream languages do not have dedicated NOR and NAND operators, some lesser-known languages (for example, some "golfing" languages) do. For example, [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) has `⍱` and `⍲` for NOR and NAND, respectively.

Another class of examples can be found in hardware design languages such as [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL), [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog), etc. NAND and NOR gates are quite useful in hardware design due to usually being cheaper (requiring fewer transistors) than the equivalent circuit made from AND/OR/NOT gates, which is one of the reasons hardware design languages tend to include them; another reason is that they can be useful for certain bit-fiddling tricks.

Comment: Good catch about NAND and NOR being present in hardware description languages!

Comment: Caveat: the reason given here for the inclusion of NAND and NOR in HDL languages is no longer relevant. Modern ASIC design uses standard libraries where the number of transistors has no 1-1 relationship with the area anymore. As such the reason NAND and NOR are part of the language is mainly historical since the reasons given here used to be true.

Comment: APL is not a [golfing language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf#Dedicated_golfing_languages), but rather an array-oriented language which allows interactive development of full-stack multi-paradigm applications with industrial strength.

Comment: @Adám: [Bingo](http://dilbert.com/strip/1994-02-22).

Comment: @EricDuminil :-) It is all true though.

Comment: @EricDuminil No, really. APL is not a golfing language, it's a practical language that happens to be good at golfing. Perl is similar in this regard, no?

Comment: And I don't think that the two successive "for example" clauses ever claimed to be the same example.

Comment: @Pavel Being a practical language and a golfing language isn't mutually exclusive. I've seen people successfully golf with Python.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Of course you have! I golf in Python and Ruby and C# myself. But they weren't *made* for golfing.

Comment: OP didn't actually say that APL was a “golfing” language, btw.

Answer (score 47):

No, there is no `nor` operator in any high level mainstream programming language.

### Why ?

Mainly because it is difficult to read:

- it requires the mental combination of several operators ( "*and not*", or in a more literary style : ["*further negative*", "*each untrue*"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nor))
- it implies an implicit `not` on the first operand, but the reader only understand this afterwards
- it is different from human languages, which use an explicit negation on the first operand, such as "*neither x nor y*", "*nor x nor y*".  So a reader might confuse `(x nor y)` with `(x and not y)` instead of `((not x) and (not y))`
- some readers are confused with the apparent `or` semantic which doesn't apply

### But it's so common in hardware...

`nor` is an elementary [hardware gate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) that can be used to make all the other logical gates. So one could argue that all the other logical operators are combinations and `nor` is the simplest elementary logical operator.

However, what's true for the hardware is not necessarily true to the humans. And despite it's popularity at hardware level, some mainstream CPUs do not even offer a `NOR` in their assembler instruction set (e.g. [x86](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.xml)).

### Alternatives

Readability matters. And sometimes it can be improved by other means.

#### Use of existing operators

For example:

```
if x not in [1,2]    // use of 'in' or 'not in' operator instead of x!=1 and x!=2
```

#### Ordering of conditions

```
if x==1 or x==2 
     action A
else 
     action B
```

instead of

```
if x!=1 and x!=2 
    action B
else 
    action A
```

#### Use of until loop

Some languages also offer loop instructions that allow to express conditions either with `while` or with `until`, letting you choose the more "positive" way.  These instructions are for example  `until c do ...` in [ruby](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm), `do until c ...` in [vb](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/beginner/Do-Until-Loop.html), or `repeat ... until c` in [pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/REPEAT..UNTIL) and its descendants.

For example:

```
Until (x==1 or x==2) do
     ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
While (x!=1 and x!=2)
    ...
```

#### Make a function

Now if you still prefer the `nor` syntax,  you could define a function, but only if you don't expect a shortcut to happen:

```
If ( nor(x,y) )   // attention, x and y will always be evaluated
    ...
```

There is a readability advantage of the function over the operator, because the reader immediately understands that the negation applies to all arguments. In some languages you can define a function with a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Funny, I usually write that as `while (not (x == 1 or x == 2))` as I find the `x != 1 and x != 2` version hard to read, and find "x is neither 1, nor 2" much easier to process than "x is not 1, and x is not 2".

Comment: Those two loops are not equivalent...

Comment: @Baldrickk can you elaborate?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful `Repeat`... `Until` always executes the loop body at least once. If x is 1, the loop body is still executed, but not repeated. The `While` loop won't execute the body in this case.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I was leaving that as a simple exercise to the reader ;)  As sina says, the first one executes the body at least once, but the while may not execute the body at all.  To make them equivalent, you need to test the condition prior to entering the first loop.

Comment: @Baldrickk yes you are completely right.  When I write equivalent, I was only speaking about the loop condition, as the boolean operators were the subject of the question. Thank you, i'll reword it to clarify

Comment: @Mael interesting! For me it really depends on the intent and the meaning of the terms being logically connected. Set operation could also help to make it readable when available (e.g. python's ’x in [1,2,8]’ and ’x not in [1,2]’). However the question seems more general, as it's not only about == and != but also > and <= as well as any other boolean condition

Comment: FWIW NOR is not the "combination of several operators"; it's a basic logical operator like the others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR "The computer used in the spacecraft that first carried humans to the moon, the Apollo Guidance Computer, was constructed entirely using NOR gates with three inputs."

Comment: @Mael, except that "x is neither 1 or 2" has the same meaning no? so in essence your qualm could be be settled with a niether function or operator, rather than a nor operator, eg `if(x is neither a, b, c..)`, and then at that point, you might as well just use not. `if(x is not a, b, c)` and for better parsing for python (knowing when the statement ends better) `if x is not a, b, or c:` and you could similarly do if `x is a, b or c:`.  Really what your asking for isn't nor, but better logic syntax with the same symbols we currently use.

Comment: Wether x and y in `nor(x,y)` are always evaluated depends on the language and how `nor()` is implemented. There are languages (D, Io, …) where the called function can decide if and when to evaluate arguments.

Comment: @user1936 fair point: NOR is an elementary HW gate that is used to make all the other gates. But strictly speaking, this kind of NOR is not a logical operator but an [gate implementing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) the behavior of the logical operator. I also agree that NOR can be defined directly by its truth table. For a human brain however, NOR is still the combination of AND NOT (or in more literary style: ["further negative", "each untrue"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nor)).  X86 assembler also [doesn't know NOR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.xml)

Comment: I'm not sure that "nor" would be useful, but in many contexts "and not" would be helpful in cases where it's necessary to clear a specified set of bits in a value.  Something like `uint64a = uint64b & ~0x40000000;` will work to clear one bit, but `uint64a = uint64b & ~0x80000000;` may clear all of the top 33 bits.  A proper "and not" operator would not have such a problem.  Incidentally, the ARM instruction set has an "and not" instruction, called "bic" [bit clear].

Comment: @supercat interesting thoughts ! ARM has also an ORN instruction (which is another name for NOR).  This raises the question of bitwise NOR vs. logical NOR

Comment: @Christophe: I think ORN is "OR NOT, isn't it?  I can't think of many cases where ORN would be useful; it's more likely part of the instruction set because so many other instructions have complement forms that making "OR" do otherwise would have required more work.  The thing about BIC is that it's used a lot; probably more than "AND" in cases where the resulting value will be of interest (as opposed to code just wanting to know if the result is zero).

Answer (score 19):

@KilianFoth's comment on the question is spot on.

You can synthesize `nor` from `not` and `or`:

```
if (x nor y)
```

is exactly the same as

```
if (not (x or y))
```

Introducing `nor` as a separate operator would introduce redundancies to the language, which are neither needed, nor wanted (or - which are not needed and not wanted).

Similarly, I am not aware of any language having a `nand` operator - probably because it can be synthesized from `not` and `and` operators.

You could, in theory, create a language with only `nand` or only `nor` operators. All of `and`, `or`, and `not` could then by synthesied from them.
The only problem is that this would be ridiculously unwieldy.
For examples, see [NOR logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic) and [NAND logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic) on Wikipedia.

Comment: The redundancies could also be not needed or wanted :)

Comment: @Dave That pun was intended, glad to see you noticed ;-)

Comment: Redundancies alone don’t really explain why `nor` isn’t included. Otherwise, why do languages have `and` and `or`? They’re redundant, thanks to De Morgan. In fact, you could substitute all three conventional logical operators (`and`, `or`, `not`) by providing *just* `nor`, as you rightly observed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good question, actually... I'd say because people are accustomed to having `and`, `or`, and `not` available, and it's easy to synthesize other operators if you have all of them. It was not immediately obvious to me how `and` can be synthesized `not` and `or`, and `or` from `not` and `and`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Technically, all you need is [a lambda operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). The reason we do more is to match the mental model most programmers have. Most programmers think of logic in terms of `and`, `or` and `not` -- because that's what most human languages use. Once you match the mental model of and/or/not, then nor & nand become redundant. Their redundancy is even encoded in their names: "n(ot )and" and "n(ot )or". If we had distinct, pre-existing English terms for them, and not just synthesized ones, then you'd probably see them more often.

Comment: Re redundancy as argument: There are languages with more than `not`, `and`, `or`. For instance some BASIC dialects (GW-BASIC, QuickBASIC, …) have exclusive or XOR, implication IMP (→ NOT(x XOR y)), and equivalence EQV (→ NOT(x) OR y) as additional operators.

Comment: @BlackJack: I've not encountered much use for the operators you describe; the ones I've found lacking are "X and not Y" [with Y being promoted to X's type before the negation] and a ternary form of either "(X and not Z) xor Y", or "X xor ((X xor Y) and Z)" (each of the latter two is more useful than the other in some cases where (Y and not Z) is non-zero, but their biggest usefulness comes in cases where (Y and not Z) is zero and the two operations would be equivalent.

Comment: @R.M. Just to clarify, mine was a rhetorical question. I knew the reason; my point was that “redundancy” isn’t it.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) and some of its dialects have *[nor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR)* (and *[nand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke)*). In APL, *nor* is denoted `⍱` (since `∨` is *or* and `~` is *not*):

```apl
∇ result←ExampleOne color
  :If (color≡'green')⍱(color≡'blue')
      result←'warm'
  :Else
      result←'cold'
  :EndIf
∇

∇ result←ExampleTwo(x y)
  :If x⍱y
      result←'x is false and y is false'
  :Else
      result←'at least one of them is true'
  :EndIf
∇
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVA7EoIwFOxzitcFCmegtaegsvEC0bygM4EwIQzhAn4KZ7yCR/BKuQgGcRAGTbe7ebv7HivlirdMqqzr3OUMGqtaGne6J5blpcRNgbBXUmkCsE4FBG/grg@aacSChu72/HI7WSMN/df@jVa0YTqnvUEiK1yofpoPasFTQXwLQn5V2TYqsNCGnybWJ7cLMwvHCgTzOcAKDu0I/@czAxJZZUD5XZUAc8C8HzO6xnmvrptcZViWTBmNfCR8W4ggmsN4CuO5GkP8Ag)

Answer (score 10):

This answer is from the assembler language for a computer made in the mid 1960s.  That's pretty obscure, but in some respects it addresses your question.

DEC (Digital Equipment Corporation) launched the PDP-6 computer in the mid 1960s.  This machine had a total of 64 instructions that were boolean operations on two operands (including some degenerate cases).  These 64 instructions were really 16 operators with 4 variants in each operator.

Two of the operators,  ANDCB and ORCB implemented NOR and NAND respectively  (unless I am mixed up on the double negative logic).   You can see the   [opcode table](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/opcodes.html#4).  The opcode table is actually for the PDP-10 computer, a successor to the PDP-6.

If you look at the numerical instruction in binary, it gets more interesting.  It turns out that for all the opcodes in the range 400-477 (octal), four bits in the instruction itself provide a four bit truth table for 16 possible boolean operators.  Some of these operators ignore one or both of the inputs.  For example SETZ and SETO ignore both of the inputs.

The designers of the PDP-6 exploited this fact to implement all these instructions with less logic than it would have taken to implement only some of them.  Some of these instructions appeared rarely, if ever, in assembly language code.  But they were all there.

So ANDCB is the equivalent of NOR.  (again, unless I got my logic backwards, in which case ORCB is the equivalent).

Answer (score 4):

The `nor` operator as you described it would not be repeatable, which is bound to lead to lots of difficult to spot bugs.

Your "Example 2" is essentially this:

```
if (false nor false) {
becomes
if (true) {
```

But try that again with three variables and see what happens:

```
if (false nor false nor false) {
becomes
if ((false nor false) nor false) {
becomes
if (true nor false) {
becomes
if (false) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl has the `unless` keyword that lets you invert conditionals:

```
unless ($color eq 'green' or $color eq 'blue') {
    # code
}
```

While not NOR operator, you can express your intent in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can write your own nor operator, except operator names cannot use letters, so maybe call it |!| and nand &!& or !|| and !&&. Second argument would be an autoclosure like in the || and && operators.

Yes, it doesn’t work as nice a && or ||. A nor with three operands not(a or b or c) would be (a or b) nor c or a nor (b or c). Basically one item in an or chain needs to be replaced with nor.

(a nor b) nor c would be (a or b) and not c which is not the same as a nor (b nor c).